# Is there a way to use Casperjs + Tor on windows?

Tags: casperjs, tor

I've been searching for a while but can't figure it out. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking better received questions. It's good to add what you have tried or add links to documentation you read.

Comment: Tor can be used as a proxy, so I think so.

Answer (score 1):

Tor is socks5 proxy not normal proxy and it can work with casperjs , but you have to open tor first and make sure connection to tor network is done

Then from command line use:

```
casperjs  --proxy=127.0.0.1:9150 --proxy-type=socks5 test.js
```

If you closed tor application it's will lost the socks connection